# How do I include a header file located in a specific folder? (C++)

Tags: c++, file, header, include

I want to include a specific header file (MyHeader.h) in a C++ project. The solution for my project is located in the folder:

```
C:\\Projects\\MyProgram
```

The header file is located in the folder:

```
C:\\Projects\\MyProgram\\Files
```

I tried the following line of code, but it doesn't work.

```
#include <Files\MyHeader.h>
```

Is there an easy way to include the header file without adding the full path to "Include directories" in the configuration properties?

Thanks in advance for any help. :)

Comment: Have you tried `#include "C:\\Projects\\MyProgram\\Files\\MyHeader.h"`? If you want you can use relative path as well, but relative to the cpp file, so if the cpp file is also in `Files` then you can use `#include "MyHeader.h"`, but if the cpp file is in `OtherFiles` under `MyProgram`, then you need to use: `#include "..\\Files\\MyHeader.h"`.

Comment: You need either a full or relative path to the include directory, in this case C:\\Projects\\MyProgram.

If you are using Visual C++ there are various ways to do this, e.g. stylesheets.

Comment: Which ide (or compiler) are you using? you need to add the path in your ide and ultimately as part of the compiler command line.

Comment: triple_r's solution of the full path is not the best one you don't want to do that. The relative path is ok.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
#include "files/myheader.h"
```

It will work if the header is in a `files` folder in the same directory as the current source.

---

If you're trying to include a 3rd party library and not your own header, I'd suggest you to save the library headers in a particular path (say `C:\Library\headers`). (If there are static libraries put them in some other path like `C:\Library\lib`).

1. In your Visual Studio C++ Project, go to `View > Other Windows > Property Manager`.

[image: Property Manager Window]

2. Double Click on the Project Name. You will see a dialog box like this:

[image: Property Page Editor]

Make sure `All Configurations` is chosen in the dropdown, if you want the change to be applied to both the Debug and the Release Configurations. Else just choose the Configuration you want the properties to be applied to.

3. Go to VC++ Directories on the left and choose Include Directories in the right, and enter the path(s) in the textbox separated by a `;`.

*You can also use the drop down and use the Dialog box to add the paths if you'd prefer to browse to each path separately*

[image: Edit1]
[image: Edit2]

4. Add the library path the same way to `Library Directories`
5. Save the changes using the Save button on the Property Manager Pane's toolbox.

---

You will then be able to access the header file contained in the directory you added by something like:

```
#include <myheader.h>
```

This approach will help, because it won't matter where the headers saved. The header path is not hard-coded.

---

Comment: @user4067575 are you using Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't matter anymore. The problem's fixed.

Comment: This would work only if the source file is in the directory of the solution, and not a side project.

The correct way is to include the solution directory in the include search path.

Comment: @user4067575 Check update. It uses VS property pages. Will help make your include paths look cleaner.

Answer (score 5):

The current directory of the source file is always searched, although if you use angled brackets it is searched after your include path, whilst if you use quotes it will be the first directory searched.

The directory of your solution or makefile/project file is irrelevant, **the local path is relative to the compilation unit, i.e. the cpp file.**

If that cpp file includes a header, that headers own includes are relative to itself, not the cpp file that included it. (It would be hell to manage if it were not).

Ideally you should use forward slashes in paths too.

Your actual correct setup here is to include the solution directory in your search path. If it is Visual Studio you can use a macro for this, `$(SolutionDir)` I think.

That means that if anyone else is going to build your solution, they can put it in a directory they choose and as long as the structure underneath is the same, it will still work.

To use a relative path in your cpp file without any include directory settings, you might need something like:

```
#include "../Files/MyHeader.h"
```

Comment: I don't see a +1 only a -1 on here and of course a silent one. There is nothing wrong with my answer. The user is giving insufficient information to solve his problem.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to replace your brackets `<>` with double quotes `""` like this:

```
#include "Files\MyHeader.h"
```

Brackets is used when you want Visual Studio to find the path from your project settings and double quotes when you want to access the header from a specific path or relative to your project.